# Отправка сообщений Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, sendmail

У меня проблема, разрабатываю сайт и нужно сделать отправку сообщений на почту админу. Только проблема в том, пользователь должен иметь сам меня почту на какую отправлять с административной модели. Но я не знаю как организовать мои конфигурационные файлы. Человек который будет пользоваться сайтом не сможет настроить api мailgun. Есть ли способ задать такие значение, при которым отправка сообщения не будет требовать MAIL_USERNAME и MAIL_PASSWORD. Ниже представлен код отправки писем.

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'text' => 'required'
        ]);
        $data = $request->all();

        Mail::send('email', ['data' => $data], function ($m) use ($data) {

            $m->from($data['email']);
            $m->to('testing-1dbb32dqw@inbox.mailtrap.io', 'Mr.Admin')->subject('Новое уведомление');
        });

    }

}
```

Также .env файл

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю какой email они будут использовать для своего администратора. По этому подскажи, кто сталкивался и как нужно правильно и по хорошему это делать. Может мне нужно обращаться к заказчику и просить все данные или можно обойтись без этого. Но так, что бы при получении сайта их почта была настроена и работала.

Comment: Я бы создал в .ENV значение MAIL_TO= адрес админа, а затем в нужном месте его получил env("MAIL_TO", "somedefaultvalue"); .ENV может быть у каждого разный, это удобно. Есть возможность не лезть в код, а настроить всю конфигурацию в одном месте.

Answer (score -1):

```
$to = "xxx@mail.ru";  //кому
$subject = "subject";
$txt = "text";
$headers = "From: xxx@mail.ru" . "\r\n"; //от кого 
mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
```

вот пример